# How to through NAT with PPPoE?

Tags: c, networking, nat, pppoe

I want to create a route server to proxy some clients(they may not in the same intranet) to access internet. I need to assign unique ip to the client and get the ip when packets response，so I can do some monitor task. i want to know if I use PPPoE server to deal with this case, how to through NAT ? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. NAT routes packets in the [Transport layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer), but PPPoE operates in the [Data Link layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Link_Layer); NAT can't even *see* PPPoE packets.

Comment: ok. what about VPN(PPTP) ? and Is there any good method? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to setup a Gateway Machine with which all your clients connect and on that machine simply setup NAT. For monitoring if there are few clients, simply setup wireshark and log traffic, if it's big, attach dedicated logging server and put your gateway server ethernet connected to this sevrver in promiscous mode, log al traffic and have fun,